# ELK Stack or Logentries for large scale projects?

Tags: logging, server, elastic-stack, logentries

My clients usually don't monitor server logs. They just store them, and that's all.  Although my company want to help clients with analysing 404 errors. 
The first idea, which comes to my mind is to download log from server. But it's have some disadvantages. It doesn't work in real time, our client have to send logs for us, etc.  Logs are comparatively big ~1gb/day.
We want something which works in near real time. We need custom dashboard concerning about 404 errors, as it's our interest. Then we want to see, what catalog "generate" most of 404 errors, what are referers, which ref to 404 error, etc. Alerting is important feature for us. Also we want to see, how things have been changing during some period of time.  It would work like this: all infrastructure is on our client servers, then we have access to logs search engine + logs visualization custom dashboard
What tool would you suggest for me?  I've heard about ELK Stack and Logentries, Splunk. SPlunk is horribly expensive. What kind of software will fit our needs? Please keep in mind that my clients have comparatively big log diary (1gb/day).

Thanks you in advance for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Logentries has been designed for exactly what you describe above - easy to use, real time search and analytics for your log data. I'm biased so I'd recommend checking out a free trial to see for your self - you'll be setup in minutes.

Some folks use ELK but the hassle factor with having to manage/configure/maintain the ELK stack can be off putting and time consuming and ultimately expensive.